# class that trigger when file change

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I want to store an actually version of each filename into a textfile. And i want to update the textfile if a file changes

How can i look if file in given directory changes? for example changes file name or size e.g.?
using C#

i have tried to look at all files using `System.IO` in a loop every 10 seconds but i hope there is a better way to do

**Is there a class in c# which fires when files changed?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, there is

[FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)